# Angular,IONIC getting value for each category

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm implementing a rating at IONIC, although this is basically angular. I want to get the value for each category. If I qualify rubric "animals" I want to get the value I selected. If I qualify "cars" I want to get the value I selected.

My problem is that I always get the same value for both categories. What can I do? I want to know what is the best solution because then I think creating dynamic code and do not want to repeat code in n categories.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1PomwzklGD2Y8esbsnxT?p=preview

```
// .html //
What do you think about the animals?
<ionic-ratings ratingsobj='ratingsObject'></ionic-ratings>
What do you think about the cars??
<ionic-ratings ratingsobj='ratingsObject'></ionic-ratings>

// .js //
$scope.ratingsObject = {
 iconOn: 'ion-ios-star', //Optional
 iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',  //Optional
 iconOnColor: 'rgb(200, 200, 100)',  //Optional
 iconOffColor: 'rgb(200, 100, 100)', //Optional
 rating: 4,  //Optional
 minRating: 1, //Optional
 readOnly:false, //Optional
 callback: function(rating) {  //Mandatory    
  $scope.ratingsCallback(rating);
 }
};

$scope.ratingsCallback = function(rating) {
 $scope.cars=rating;
 $scope.animals=rating;
 console.log('Selected rating is : ', rating);

 //is the same value :(
 console.log("animals: "+$scope.animals);
 console.log("cars: "+$scope.cars);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create two rating object to handle ratings separately.

**controller code:**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic-ratings'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.myTitle = 'IONIC RATINGS DEMO';

 $scope.ratingsObject = {
iconOn: 'ion-ios-star', //Optional
iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',  //Optional
iconOnColor: 'rgb(200, 200, 100)',  //Optional
iconOffColor: 'rgb(200, 100, 100)', //Optional
rating: 4,  //Optional
minRating: 1, //Optional
readOnly:false, //Optional
callback: function(rating) {  //Mandatory    
  $scope.ratingsCallback(rating, 'cars');
}
};

$scope.ratingsObject2 = {
iconOn: 'ion-ios-star', //Optional
iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',  //Optional
iconOnColor: 'rgb(200, 200, 100)',  //Optional
iconOffColor: 'rgb(200, 100, 100)', //Optional
rating: 4,  //Optional
minRating: 1, //Optional
readOnly:false, //Optional
callback: function(rating) {  //Mandatory    
  $scope.ratingsCallback(rating,'animals');
}
};

$scope.ratingsCallback = function(rating,category) {
    console.log('Selected rating is : ', rating);

if(category === 'cars') {
      $scope.cars=rating;
      console.log("cars: "+$scope.cars);
}else {
     $scope.animals=rating;

console.log("animals: "+$scope.animals); 
}

};

});
```

**html:**

```
<ion-view>
<h1 class="text-center">{{myTitle}}</h1>
<div>
  What do you think about the animals?
  <ionic-ratings ratingsobj='ratingsObject'></ionic-ratings>
  What do you think about the cars??

  <ionic-ratings ratingsobj='ratingsObject2'></ionic-ratings>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution I had in mind. but like I said, I then will create the code dynamically. then you have to create n $ scope.ratingsObject ...?. I not think it's a good solution.

Comment: I am tying to fix this.